# Copying a contex into clipboard C#

Tags: c#, windows, performance, clipboard

I found this code in stackOF but it doesn't work at all and i can't fix that.
would you tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
using System.Windows.Forms;


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `doesn't work` is _not_ a good way to explain a question. What do you mean by that? What do you expect and what is the current behaviour? Do you get any exception or error message? I strongly suggest to read [FAQ] and [ask] couple of times before you go more on Stack Overflow.

Comment: VS Provide following error :Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'SetText' does not exist in the namespace 'Clipboard' (are you missing an assembly reference?) Clipboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think your problem because you named your program with same name of class that copy text to clipboard

take look at this code

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Clipboard
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text); This will not work if you named your namespace Clipboard !
            System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text); // you should use this way to confirm you need to access to clipboard not your namespace
        }
    }
}
```

i named my program with same name of class(Clipboard)
and i have problem now because the compiler confusing between your program and class that copy a text
So the best way is to specify a unique name each time you create a program :)

Comment: Nicely spotted. I agree - there is a conflict.

Comment: Bravo my brother...exactly...i wondered you spotted the issue quickly...thank you so much bro!!

Comment: @mohammadhoseinsheikhi Glad that the problem has been solved :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a namespace conflict with your own. You can either explicitly use the exact Clipboard.SetText() method using the full declaration as per @WaleedKhaled's answer:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
```

or else the using statement at the top of your example to say something like:

```
using WinForms = System.Windows.Forms;
```

then your line would read:

```
WinForms.Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
```